# How to upload file in firebase file storage in Android Studio?

Tags: android, android-studio, firebase, firebase-storage

I am building an android application in which I am using firebase database for storage of files. But I am getting an error and after that error my program keeps running but never goes into the `onsuccessListener()`. Please help me out in this.
My code is like this

```
 Intent intent=new Intent();
 intent.setType("image/*");
 intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
 startActivityForResult(intent,gallery_intent);
```

The code for StartActivityForResult.

```
if(requestCode==gallery_intent && resultCode==RESULT_OK){
        uri=data.getData();
        progressDialog.setMessage("Uploading...");
        progressDialog.show();
        FirebaseStorage storage=FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
        StorageReference storageReference=storage.getReference().child("Ad Posts");

try {
           storageReference.putFile(uri).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                @Override
                public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                    Toast.makeText(ServiceProvider.this, "Ad Successfully added to the database", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            });
        }catch (Exception e){
        }
    }
```

the Error I am getting is.

```
E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
                     com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
                         at com.google.android.gms.dynamite.DynamiteModule.zza(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.<init>(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.zzj(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzacy(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacO(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                         at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                         at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                         at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/UploadTask: Unable to create a network request from metadata
          android.os.RemoteException
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.<init>(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.zzj(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzacy(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacO(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
              at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
              at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
              at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                android.os.RemoteException
                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.<init>(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.zzj(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzacy(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacO(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
                An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
                 Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
E/StorageException: null
                android.os.RemoteException
                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.<init>(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzbud.zzj(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzacy(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzacO(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
                    at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$8.run(Unknown Source)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1133)
                    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:607)
                    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:761)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
public static final int PICK_IMAGE = 1;
public static final int GALLERY_REQUEST = 1;

// Uri indicates, where the image will be picked from
private Uri filePath;
    
// instance for firebase storage and StorageReference
FirebaseStorage storage;
StorageReference storageReference;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_my_account);

    // get the Firebase  storage reference
    storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();
    storageReference = storage.getReference();


    dp.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent photoPickerIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_PICK);
            photoPickerIntent.setType("image/*");
            startActivityForResult(photoPickerIntent, GALLERY_REQUEST);
        }
    });
}

@Override
public void onActivityResult ( int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
        switch (requestCode) {
            case GALLERY_REQUEST:
                Uri selectedImage = data.getData();
                filePath = data.getData();
                try {
                    Bitmap bitmap = 
     MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MyAccount.this.getContentResolver(), selectedImage);
                    // uploadImage();
                    dp.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    if (filePath != null) {
                        // Code for showing progressDialog while uploading
                        final ProgressDialog progressDialog
                                = new ProgressDialog(MyAccount.this);
                        progressDialog.setTitle("Uploading...");
                        progressDialog.show();
                        //Uri file = Uri.fromFile(new File(String.valueOf(bitmap)));
                        final StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child("foldername/"+userId+"/" + UUID.randomUUID().toString());
                        riversRef.putFile(filePath);
                        UploadTask uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(filePath);

                        //: if request.auth != null

                        Task<Uri> urlTask = uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                            @Override
                            public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                                if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    throw task.getException();
                                }

                                // Continue with the task to get the download URL
                                    return riversRef.getDownloadUrl();
                                }
                            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                                @Override
                                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                                    Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                                    FirebaseUser user = FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser();

                                    rootNode = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
                                    reference = rootNode.getReference("CustomerDP");
                                    DPadapter helper = new DPadapter(downloadUri.toString(),userId);
                                                
                                    reference.child(userId).setValue(helper);

                                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                                    Toast.makeText(MyAccount.this, "Image Uploaded!!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                                } else {
                                    // Handle failures
                                    // ...
                                }
                            }
                        });
                    }
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    Log.i("TAG", "Some exception " + e);
                    Toast.makeText(MyAccount.this, "Not uploading images", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
                break;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Hi Infinity. Thank you for your answer. But while this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding why and/or how this code answers the question improves its long-term value. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). Kind Regards.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to upload image on firebase database please refer below link it is great demo for upload image on firebase

[Click here](https://www.simplifiedcoding.net/firebase-storage-tutorial-android/)

Comment: What's the problem are you getting?

Comment: `StorageReference riversRef = storageReference.child("images/pic.jpg");`

where `images => main node refrence `
           `pic.jpg = > Image name`

Answer (score 0):

Probably, Google Play Services are not updated on your device.

Comment: @user7744006 Sign in gmail account on your laptop and then go on Google Play web and search Google Play Services then click Install there. It will push update over the air.